# how do i determine the label for a checkboxrow in bootstrap for yii?

Tags: checkbox, twitter-bootstrap, yii

hello i'm having problems with the labels of checkboxes. when i use more than one model of the same class in a single view the checkboxes seem not to use the names from attributeLabels of that model.

i.e. if i have this in my view:

```
$form->checkBoxRow($colorArray['left'],'[left]special_request');
```

the checkbox get rendered with a label "[left]special request" instead of "Special Request" as stated in the attributeLabels of the Color model.

on the other hand dropdown lists, text field, etc are rendered correctly.

i have noticed this bug/feature after updating bootstrap from version 0.9.12.r211 to 1.0.0.r296.

Answer (score 1):

The `checkBoxRow` and all methods ended with `Row` get the label from the array returned by `Model->attributeLabels()`.

You can either change the autogenerated labels or use the `TbLabel` widget.
Choose the best for your issue.

Comment: Thanks to you I remembered we can do this by specifying the attributeLabels() array as mentioned here http://www.larryullman.com/2009/11/10/basic-model-edits-in-yii/

Comment: in the mean time i updated yii to 1.1.13 and exchanged yii-bootstrap with yii-booster 1.0.5.7.

right now this issue simply disappeared by itself.